# Is it possible to "Scale" width and height any widget in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Stack widget which hosts a Box and an Image.
As the state changes, I want to scale the Box widget by whatever value the state has, for example by 2x.

I couldn't find anything about scaling the widgets on the Modifier or Box properties so I decided to react to the state changes by manipulating the size using "Modifier.size" which is not ideal for me.

So is there support for scaling the widgets or should I manually play with the size property?

-Thanks

```
@Composable
fun Pointer(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, state: TransitionState, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Stack(modifier) {
        Box(
            shape = CircleShape, backgroundColor = Color.Gray.copy(alpha = .3f),
            modifier = Modifier.size(state[width])
        )
        Image(
            asset = imageResource(id = R.drawable.ic_pointer),
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable(onClick = onClick)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you mean by your distinction between size and scale? Particularly for a `Box()`, what would a scale do that a size would not? IOW, what does "is not ideal for me" mean?

Comment: Ok, I don't want to care about the size of the box or explicitly keep a reference to it. I only want to pass for example 2, and then get the width/height of the box multiplied by 2, 
or pass 0.4 and get the width/height multiplied by 0.4 from whatever value it has.

Comment: What I mean exactly is the same view.scale() thing that we use to animate the view in Android View System

Comment: A `Box()` does not *have* a size, except what you tell it to draw. There is no "get the width/height of the box", except what you tell it to draw. You are thinking in terms of stateful views, and that is not how Compose works. So, `Modifier.size()` seems like the correct answer. "I don't want to care about the size of the box or explicitly keep a reference to it" -- you do not have a choice in the matter.

Comment: @CommonsWare you should write that as an answer and it should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 8):

#### Compose 1.0.0-alpha08

As time passes by, there is a new compose version which [renames](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1507817) 'drawLayer' to 'graphicsLayer' and adds a new [scale](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).scale(kotlin.Float,%20kotlin.Float)) modifier (uses 'graphicsLayer' underneath).

Thus composable will look like:

```
@Composable
fun Pointer(scale: Float, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box(modifier) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .matchParentSize()
                .scale(scale)
                .background(Color.Cyan, CircleShape)
        )
        Image(
            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Done,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.Center)
        )
    }
}
```

#### Compose 1.0.0-alpha07 (original answer)

I believe you may achive the desired behavior with [drawLayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/package-summary#drawlayer) modifier. For example a simple composable, which displays an scalable circle and an unscalable icon on top of it:

```
@Composable
fun Pointer(scale: Float, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box(modifier) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .matchParentSize()
                .drawLayer(scaleX = scale, scaleY = scale)
                .background(Color.Cyan, CircleShape)
        )
        Image(
            asset = Icons.Filled.Done,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.Center)
        )
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
Pointer(
    scale = 1f,
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Magenta)
        .padding(25.dp)
        .preferredSize(50.dp)
        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
)
```

[When scale = 1f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvR4W.png)

[When scale = 2f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8cCS.png)

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to care about the size of the box or explicitly keep a reference to it

That is going to be a problem. In Compose, widgets like `Box()` are stateless functions. You cannot ask a `Box()` how big it is — instead, you need to *tell* the `Box()` how big it is, using a suitable `Modifier`.

Frequently, "how big it is" is a fixed value or rule, set in the code (e.g., `Modifier.size(200.dp)`). You should be able to have the size be dependent upon some state that you track yourself, so long as that state is a `State`, so Compose knows to recompose (call your function again) when that `State` changes. If you go that route, then scaling is a matter of checking the current `State` value, applying your scale factor, and using the result for the new `State` value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, since the whole APIs are alpha and tons of TODOs are visible in the source code of Compose, I will upvote your question, for now, to see where Compose ends up.
Thanks again for your help